# Get filepath of importing file at compile time

Tags: crystal-lang

If I have a file that's meant to be required by other files, is it possible to get the absolute filepath of the file that's requiring it?

So if `lib_file.cr` has a macro that is meant to be called by the `app_file.cr` that imported it, can that macro discover the filepath to `app_file.cr` at compile time?

I tried stuff like this:

```
macro tester
  puts __DIR__
  puts __FILE__
end
```

But when invoked from the file doing the requiring, it gives nothing at compile time and this at runtime:

```
?
expanded macro: app_file
```

If I change the macro to this:

```
macro tester
  {{puts __DIR__}}
  {{puts __FILE__}}
end
```

It gives me this at compile time:

```
"/home/user/Documents/crystal_test/lib_file"
"/home/user/Documents/crystal_test/lib_file.cr"
```

So is there a trick to get the full path to `app_file.cr` inside `lib_file.cr` at compile time?

Comment: I also tried putting `puts __FILE__` in a separate file and using `{{run(...).stringify}}`, but that gives me the path to that separate file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use default args with `__FILE__` to get the file that is calling the macro.

```rb
macro tester(file = __FILE__)
  {{puts file}} # Print at compile time
  puts {{file}} # Print at runtime
end
```

Comment: you have also `__LINE__` so you can get where the macro was called from.  I used at https://gist.github.com/bcardiff/740e8c1f7c7fbc456bb0 .  Yet there is way AFAIK to know the file that is requiring the lib without using a macro, which was your original question.

Comment: Thanks, it looks promising, but it's giving me `undefined local variable or method 'file'`. I'll investigate further.

Comment: ...ah yes, it needs `{{puts file}}`. Seems to work perfectly. Thank you!